# Understanding FSK and FHSS combination

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, fsk

I am having trouble to understand how to combine Frequency Shift Keying (FSK) with Frequency Hopping Spread Spectrum (FHSS). As far as I understand, A IQ FSK-modulated signal $s(t)$ can be written as
$$
s(t)
=
\Re
\{
A\exp[j(2\pi f_c(t) t + \varphi)]
\},
$$
where the instantaneous frequency $f_c(t)$ is given by
$$
f_c(t)
=
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}
A_k(t)
g(t - kT_s)
+
f_0(t)
\quad
\text{with }
A_k(t) \, \in \{-1, +1\} \, (\forall k, \, \forall t)
$$
where $g(\cdot)$ is the pulse-shaping function ($T_s$ being the symbol duration), and $f_0(t)$ is the instantaneous carrier frequency, in the given hop set.

My questions are:

- are the expressions of $s(t)$ and $f_c(t)$ given above valid ?
- is my understanding of FSK and FHSS correct ?

Comment: Your $f_c(t)$ is a complex-valued function, and so when multiplied by $j2\pi$ etc gives a real-valued function in the argument of the $\exp$. Thus, $\exp[j(2\pi f_c(t)t+\cdots] = \exp[r(t) + j\cdots]$ so that $s(t)$ is actually a sinusoid with exponentially increasing or decreasing amplitude, and not FSK at all.  Also, (slow) FH systems generally transmit _multiple_ bits at the same frequency-hopped carrier frequency before the carrier is hopped to the next frequency in the frequency-hopping pattern.

Comment: Hello @DilipSarwate, thank you for your answer. You are right, if I have the term $B_k(t)$ in the expression of $f_c(t)$ I will indeed have a real component inside the exponential, thanks for pointing that out. So, if I only keep the $A_k(t)$, is the expression then that of a FSK signal ? Have a nice day, Alex.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to remove $B_k$ etc, and while you are at it, delete the last sentence. Thanks and pleasantries such as “Have a nice day” are specifically called out as undesirable. You can edit your question by clicking on the link marked Edit below your post.